# Как подключить БД Access к макету сайта HTML+CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, access

Стоит задача подключить БД, которая разработана в MS Access, к макету сайта на HTML+CSS/JS. Все выше указанное находиться на ПК. 
Как сделать эту задачу? Где читать материалы по этому вопросу?
Если есть готовые решения - Буду признателен!

Comment: Если же Access не подходит под эту задачу, то какие БД нужно использовать? И на каких ресурсах взять информацию касательно их подключения к HTML файлу

Comment: Как минимум, вам для этого необходимо "созать" серверную часть, которая с бд будет работать, будь то node.js + драйвер для работы с бд или же что-то на python/php и т.п..

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/. Подключаете подходящий OLE DB или ODBC драйвер (естественно они под винду, серверная часть тоже должна быть под нее).

Answer (score 2):

Если сайт состоит только из статической вёрстки 9HTML файл), то Access, к нему Вы никак не подключите.

Нужна серверная часть на основе какого-нибудь PHP, NodeJS, C# и т.д. Лучше C#, т.к. и он сам и Access технологии MS и хорошо дружат между собой.

P.S. Вообще использовать Access для сайта не самая лучшая затея. Всё-таки эта СУБД рассчитана в первую очередь на "домашнее" использование или небольшую фирму. Лучше используйте клиент-серверные СУБД (PostgreSQL, MySQL, MS SQL, etc).

Answer (score 1):

MS Access и в целом большинство баз данных попросту не смогут отдать данные на чистый HTML, так как в нем нет никаких функций, а только статический набор символов.

Вам нужно делать серверную часть, так как я вижу, что опыта у вас нет, то на серверной части (backend) лучше всего использовать PHP, но это уже чуть другая тема. Если вы будете использовать PHP, то к нему в пару лучше взять MySQL|PhpMyAdmin.

Если вы попросту ищете способ вывода данных из БД в HTML, то это можно реализовать с помощью JS и баз данных по типу MongoDB, которые отвечают .json файлом.